# how to work with migration in codeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have three migration like this in CodeIgniter.

1. 001_site.php
2. 002_user.php
3. 003_blog.php

by using `$this->migration->version(3)` all of migration file run and create table how can i specify which one to run ?
I could execute each migration i wanted in laravel via CLI. is it the same ?

Comment: Refer the userguide https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html#usage-example

Comment: it's just describing one migration but I have three.